# Tkinter Text: Setting tab spaces not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The following code is supposed to set the number of tab spaces when  is pressed to 4. The problem is it doesn't do that (it does 8 instead). I have looked on previous StackOverflow questions, and they are extremely darn vague. They describe using the getPixels function, but never expalin how to use it. Plus tkinter / tcl documentation is terrible so I am confused.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

def tab(arg):
    print("tab pressed")
    text.insert(tk.INSERT, " " * 4)

text.bind("<Tab>", tab)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are very close to what you need. All you need to do is add return 'break' to your tab(arg) function.  This will keep tkinter from propagating the event further. see below

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

def tab(arg):
    print("tab pressed")
    text.insert(tk.INSERT, " " * 4)
    return 'break'

text.bind("<Tab>", tab)
root.mainloop()
```

By adding the return 'break' you stop tkinter from propagating the event further.  You are getting 8 spaces, because it is taking the tab and then you are adding an additional 4 spaces on top of that.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need an event handler to do this, just configure the `Text` widget with the tab width you want:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkfont

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

font = tkfont.Font(font=text['font'])  # get font associated with Text widget
tab_width = font.measure(' ' * 4)  # compute desired width of tabs
text.config(tabs=(tab_width,))  # configure Text widget tab stops

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This solution inserts tabs instead of spaces, which is not wanted by OP, I think.

Comment: @ismailarilik: This doesn't insert tabs into anything, it just establishes where the tab stops are in the `Text` widget (and how to determine their width).

Comment: OK. I was wrong. I wanted to say that this solution _causes_ tabs are inserted instead of spaces _by the user_.

Comment: @ismailarilik: If that's the case, it would be relatively easy to remove any tabs inserted by the user and replace them with spaces—such as with the `str.expandtabs()` method.

Comment: @ismailarilik: Probably only necessary to do when the text is retrieved from any `Text` widget so configured. Regardless, the OP doesn't say they don't want tabs put in the text. What the question asks is how set the number of spaces that each one represents—something commonly referred to as "tab stops". My answer shows how to do that.