# Tkinter text replace tab with four spaces

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like to create a text widget that has the tab replaced with four spaces. Though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556147/17053202) answer by @martineau has something similar all it truly does is make the tab look/be smaller. I would like actual spaces. How can I do this? I can't use the first function showed in the linked question because then it messes with the autocomplete

Code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
keywords_list = ["from", "tkinter", "import", "Label", "Button", "Entry"]
class specialText(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = Text(self, width=50, height=10)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.text.insert(END, "# This is a test. Autocomplete works")
        self.text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)
        self.text.bind("<Tab>", self._handle_tab, add=True)

    def callback(self, word):
        #Returns possible matches
        #words is a list of almost every keyword and builtin function
        words = keywords_list
        matches = [x for x in words if x.startswith(word)]
        return matches

    def _handle_tab(self, event):
        tag_ranges= self.text.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            self.text.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.text.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.char and self.callback and event.keysym != "BackSpace":
            word = self.text.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")
            matches = self.callback(word)
            if matches:
                remainder = matches[0][len(word):]
                insert = self.text.index("insert")
                self.text.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))
                self.text.mark_set("insert", insert)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Autocomplete")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    text = specialText(window)
    text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just to be clear: you're asking how to insert four spaces if the user presses the tab key?

Comment: Yes. I can't just use `self.text.insert(INSERT, "    "); return "break"` though because that doesn't work with the autocomplete

Comment: calling the insert method is the only way to do it. If it doesn't work with autocomplete, then your autocomplete is broken. Since tkinter doesn't come with autocomplete it's impossible for us to know what the solution is.

Comment: @BryanOakley I use the autocomplete you helped me with. I added it to the question.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ [mcve] We have no way of knowing  how or when or if you ever call `_autocomplete` or `callback`. Also, why is it important that autocomplete work when you're entering spaces for tabs? What do you expect it to complete?

Comment: I just did that

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more clear what you expect to happen. When the user presses the tab key, do you want to insert four spaces, or do you want to do the autocomplete, or do you want to do both?

Comment: I want it to autocomplete when the autocomplete has started its magic and when they are not typing something in with autocomplete (I.E. not using it) then it inserts tabs. Pretty much, whenever they're not using autocomplete. The best way to understand it is to run the code

Comment: So, what's stopping you from adding an `if` statement that inserts spaces if autocomplete isn't active, and doing autocomplete if it is?

Comment: I don't know how to detect if autocomplete is active. can you show me what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean that you don't know? You clearly have a check in your code to check for autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I figured it out

### Code:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
keywords_list = ["from", "tkinter", "import", "Label", "Button", "Entry"]
class specialText(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.text = Text(self, width=50, height=10)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        self.text.insert(END, "# This is a test. Autocomplete works")
        self.text.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", self._autocomplete)
        self.text.bind("<Tab>", self._handle_tab, add=True)

    def callback(self, word):
        #Returns possible matches
        #words is a list of almost every keyword and builtin function
        words = keywords_list
        matches = [x for x in words if x.startswith(word)]
        return matches

    def _handle_tab(self, event):
        tag_ranges= self.text.tag_ranges("autocomplete")
        if tag_ranges:
            self.text.mark_set("insert", tag_ranges[1])
            self.text.tag_remove("sel", "1.0", "end")
            self.text.tag_remove("autocomplete", "1.0", "end")
            return "break"

        # Here's the difference:
        else:
            self.text.insert("    ")
            return "break"

    def _autocomplete(self, event):
        if event.char and self.callback and event.keysym != "BackSpace":
            word = self.text.get("insert-1c wordstart", "insert-1c wordend")
            matches = self.callback(word)
            if matches:
                remainder = matches[0][len(word):]
                insert = self.text.index("insert")
                self.text.insert(insert, remainder, ("sel", "autocomplete"))
                self.text.mark_set("insert", insert)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Autocomplete")
    window.geometry("500x500")
    text = specialText(window)
    text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
    window.mainloop()
```